# Question improperly closed for being too broad?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

I was hoping to have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461221/how-do-i-best-set-up-a-directory-of-test-files-in-memory-instead-of-disk-in-ne) answered, but it was closed.  Pleading in the comments for an explanation has gone unanswered, and I see no way to privately message the closers other than resorting to Twitter.  How can I get this question reopened, or at least get an explanation of how it is too broad?

I believe this question can be answered in less than a few paragraphs and only would have one or a few correct answers, one of which would be the best answer.

Comment: Seems pretty broad to me.  You're asking for an entire approach to a large problem, rather than a specific question about a specific problem.  I wouldn't say it's a *bad* question, just one that doesn't fit into this site's scope.

Comment: It isn't a large problem at all--what makes you think so?  It is also very specific--what makes you think it vague?  I'm dealing with mocking a specific .NET class, part of which may involve saving fake files in memory.

Comment: The comments above have already departed a far way from the question and narrowed down what the answer would be.  If you question is about mocking a specific .NET class then that should be the question, not what was posted.

Comment: One way to make it seem less broad is to take out the conceptual nature of the question and give us some code to play with.

Comment: Hogan, I did mention the class I was dealing with in the question.  What more do you want?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski - I don't want anything, I'm trying to help you understand how to ask questions on SO that would get results.  I can say (in general) being snide and snippy probably won't get you far.  Feel free to try prove me wrong.  I also understand sometimes it comes out that way -- I've been both of these.

Comment: Addressing not really "you", Hogan, but all of SE.  Just exasperated that I am asked to be more specific and answerable when my question is already specific and answerable.  If I am having trouble once in awhile, I think hundreds of newer/more casual users are as well.  I'm just worried that the best Q&A site will go the way of Wikipedia, with only a relative handful of contributors.  Stack Exchange should be a bit more tolerant of good questions.  Anyway, thanks very much to those who moved to reopen it.